# Error Writing trailer of rtmp FFMPEG Stream

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, stream, runtime-error, video-streaming

I'm currently playing around with ffmpeg. And I put together the following command line. But for some time now I've been encountering the problem that ffmpeg keeps giving me with the error: Error writing trailer of rtmp:[Streamlink][Streamkey]: Broken Pipe

aborts

Does anyone know a workaround?

The command looks like this: ffmpeg -re -f concat -i Playlist.txt -codec copy -flvflags no_duration_filesize -f flv rtmp://Streamlink/Streamkey

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.